# How to close excel workbook with VSTO assemblies programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

After updating in excel, there is a requirement of closing the Workbook immediately.
If I write Environment.Exit(), then it closes immediately but soon after opening again the same excel application. I tried with Globals.ThisWorkBook.Close(0); this closes the application related, sheet but I manually have to close Excel. Please help me close the Workbook after update happens.

My Application is a windows based app with VSTO assemblies(excel)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Application.Quit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.quit) method which quits Microsoft Excel. Here is what MSDN states:

> If unsaved workbooks are open when you use this method, Excel displays a dialog box asking whether you want to save the changes. You can prevent this by saving all workbooks before using the Quit method or by setting the DisplayAlerts property to False. When this property is False, Excel doesn't display the dialog box when you quit with unsaved workbooks; it quits without saving them.

> If you set the Saved property for a workbook to True without saving the workbook to the disk, Excel will quit without asking you to save the workbook.

```
For Each w In Application.Workbooks 
 w.Save 
Next w 
Application.Quit
```

Comment: It means I need to write this code in VBA Macro ? Am I right and one more doubt I would like to close only my application workbook @Eugene Astafiev

Comment: But I guess It will close all the workbooks what ever opens in system

Comment: The Excel object model is common for all kind of programming languages. You can call the `Quit` method from any language. You can close a workbook separately, but to close Excel you need to call `Quit`.